# Transitive group operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Is it true that if a group $G$ operates on the set $S$ transitively, then $|S|$ must divide $|G|$? If yes, how to prove it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, let $x\in S$, and $G_x$ the stabilizer of $x$, $|S|=|G|/|G_x|$. (Lagrange says that $|G_x|$ divides $|G|$).